# how to perform additional inner join on pivot table with laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, inner-join, laravel, pivot-table, eloquent

I have four tables:

- foods: id, name
- users: id, name
- mealtypes: id, name
- food_user: id, food_id, user_id, mealtype_id

foods and user have a many-to-many relationship
mealtype has a one-to-one relationship with food_user

In the end I would like to have an instance of a model with the following properties:
food.name, users.name, mealtype.name

normal sql would be:

```
SELECT f.name, u.name, m.name FROM foods f
INNER JOIN food_user fu ON f.id = fu.food_id
INNER JOIN users u ON fu.id = u.id 
INNER JOIN mealtypes m ON fu.mealtype_id = m.id
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this with Eloquent and Query Builder, assuming you have a model named Food:

```
$foods = Food::join('food_user', 'foods.id', '=', 'food_user.food_id')
             ->join('users', 'food_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
             ->join('mealtypes', 'food_user. mealtype_id', '=', 'mealtypes.id')
             ->get();
```

There's a good documentation about the query builder too: http://www.laravel.com/docs/queries

Comment: Thanks for reply, however, for some reason the returned object is showing the name of users correcty, but only the mealtype_id and not its name, what could be the reason?

Comment: I know now that when two tables have identical column names this happens.

Comment: Before the joins, you could do something like:

Food::select('users.name as user_name', 'foods.name as food_name', 'mealtypes.name as mealtype_name')->joins()...

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question a year later. I actually asked the wrong question. A pivot table is just a many-to-many relationship between two tables. If a table that represents this many-to-many relationship additionally relates to other tables it is not a pivot table. So in my case the table food_user should represent an eloquent entity on its own with the three relationships defined.

*Update, generic solution:*

I cannot give you my final solution in terms of Eloquent, since I haven't used it in ages (and didn't implement it there), so I do not have the knowledge anymore. In more general terms, one would need to create 4 models:

1. Food
2. User
3. MealType
4. Meal (instead of FoodUser, don't like that name)

Now, in the model Meal, you need to define your relations with the other models:

1. Meal.food has a many to one relation with Food
2. Meal.user has a many to one relation with User
3. Meal.mealType has a many to one relation with MealType
4. Some other properties such as Meal.calories (int) and Meal.date (DateTime)

Comment: I have a same situation. Can you tell me what is your final solution for this question?

Comment: Hi @AmirMojiry, I updated my answer, hopefully its helful to you.